# COLORREF to RGB

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use JavaScript to convert a `COLORREF`:

[`COLORREF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449.aspx):

> When specifying an explicit RGB color, the COLORREF value has the
>   following hexadecimal form:
>
> 0x00bbggrr
>
> The low-order byte contains a value for the relative intensity of red;
>   the second byte contains a value for green; and the third byte
>   contains a value for blue. The high-order byte must be zero. The
>   maximum value for a single byte is 0xFF.
>
> To create a COLORREF color value, use the RGB macro. To extract the
>   individual values for the red, green, and blue components of a color
>   value, use the **GetRValue**, **GetGValue**, and **GetBValue** macros,
>   respectively.

I know about `UInt32Array` but I don't know how to use it.

How can I convert from COLORREF to RGB?

It should be the opposite of this function I found:

```
 cssColorToCOLORREF: function(csscolor) {
   let rgb = csscolor.substr(1);
   let rr = rgb.substr(0, 2);
   let gg = rgb.substr(2, 2);
   let bb = rgb.substr(4, 2);
   return parseInt("0x"+bb+gg+rr);
 },
```

Comment: What input and output formats do you want? A string input (sample please), and three variables `r`, `g`,and `b`?

Comment: Thanks man input is `4294967295` output i would like 255, 255, 255. Thanks very much @Jongware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COLORREF` is typedef'ed as a `DWORD`, which is Microsoft's name for a 32-bit unsigned integer, and so its value can be split into R,G,B,A components using regular bit manipulations.

As an array:

```
input = 4294967295;
output = [
     input       & 0xff,
    (input >> 8) & 0xff,
    (input >>16) & 0xff,
    (input >>24) & 0xff
];
```

resulting in an output order as `[red, green, blue, alpha]`; or as an object:

```
output = {
    r: input       & 0xff,
    g:(input >> 8) & 0xff,
    b:(input >>16) & 0xff,
    a:(input >>24) & 0xff
};
```

resulting in `output.r`, `output.g`, `output.b` and `output.a`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! :) I didn't know you could get a from it!

Comment: You're welcome. You'd get a sensible value for Alpha only if one explicitly added it to the `COLORREF`. Microsoft's usual `RGB` macro does not add it. I guess it depends on how you got your color values.

Comment: Oh ok thanks man I'll keep that in mind :) btw does this depend on endianess? would we have to resort to [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView)?

Comment: Endianness depends on how you are retrieving those color ref values.